# Request ignored because of CORS in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I have 3 projects:

1. Client App
2. ASP.NET API App
3. IdentityServer4 MVC App

I am able to send a request from API to IDP but trying to send a request from Client to IDP yields

```
"CORS request made for path: /api/Trial/TrialAction from origin: https://localhost:44389 but
was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint"
```

even though I added the following to the IDP:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policyBuilder => policyBuilder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

and

```
// ...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthorization();
// ...
```

The interesting part is, I can send a request from API to IDP without adding CORS configuration to IDP. What am I doing wrong?

Config.cs:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> Ids =>
        new IdentityResource[]
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> Apis =>
        new ApiResource[]
        {
            new ApiResource("myapi", 
                "My API", 
                new [] { "membershipType" }
            )
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new Client[]
        { 
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mywebclient",
                ClientName = "My Web Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code, // Authorization code flow with PKCE protection
                RequireClientSecret = false, // Without client secret
                RequirePkce = true,
                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44389/authentication/login-callback" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44389/authentication/logout-callback" },
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "albidersapi"
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:44389" },
                RequireConsent = false,
            }           
        };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do yo have the client and API in the same project as IdentityServer? I typically recommend that you keep them apart.

A wild guess could be to swap these two lines:

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Because apparently IdentityServer captures the request to the API?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that your call from your client to your API is not including the access token.

The debug log is coming from [this file here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Hosting/CorsPolicyProvider.cs). If you look at where your debug statement is originating from you will see that it is checking if the path matches any within `IdentityServerOptions.Cors.CorsPaths`. Here is an image of what those paths generally are from a debug service I made.

[image: options cors paths]

These paths are just the default information and authentication endpoints for IdentityServer4. In other words it thinks your request is unauthenticated because it likely isn't including the access token.

If you are using [IdentityServer4's template logging implementation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Quickstarts/3_AspNetCoreAndApis/src/IdentityServer/Program.cs) with Serilog, then you can also add this to your `appsettings.json` to see what the ASP.NET Core CORS middleware has to say. It will be logging after IdentityServer4's log

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "Information",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what my debug log looked like when I made a request to an endpoint with a proper CORS policy, but the request didn't include its access token.

```
[21:05:47 Debug] IdentityServer.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider CORS request made for path: /api/v1.0/users/{guid}/organizations from origin: https://localhost:44459 but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint

[21:05:47 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware No CORS policy found for the specified request.
```

So it's not a CORS issue really. It's an access token or authentication issue. It is also possible, however, that your endpoint isn't being hit properly. However, you should be receiving a 404 on the client in addition to the log seen above.